# Inserting page numbers in a Google Docs document

Tags: google-drive, formatting

How do I add or insert a page number in the footer or header of a Google Docs document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Barry states in his answer you can use this option to put page numbers when printing a document. You can actually add it to the document itself with some HTML code in the header of footer section. See here: http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/03/adding-page-numbers-to-google-documents.html

Comment: Update: I was browsing through my history here and remembered this question so I thought I would put in an update saying that Google added page numbers to Docs now. See https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=83321

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on presentations.

Answer (score 4):

Page numbers are [now a part of Google Docs](http://googledocs.blogspot.com/2011/08/this-week-in-docs-page-numbers-in.html).

To include page numbers:

1. Open your document
2. Select **Insert > Page number** from the file menu
3. Choose either **Top of Page** or **Bottom of Page** to insert page numbers into the header or footer of your document respectively.

You can also include the total page count.

1. Place cursor where you want the page count total to show
2. Select **Insert > Page count** from the file menu

Placing the page count in the header or footer of one page will propagate to all pages in the document.

[image: Screencast of adding page numbers in Google docs, 07/2017]

See also [Add headers, footers & page numbers](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/86629?visit_id=1-636368364789810462-820010798&rd=1)

Comment: Unfortunately, still you cannot set custom numbering (from which page should the count start) and no Roman numbers. Hope the Google docs developers will add this soon.

Answer (score 2):

To insert page numbers you need to:

- select **Print settings** from the **File** menu
- select the checkbox marked `Include page numbers` and choose the location of the page numbers
- click **Print**

This will add page numbers to the printed (or PDF) version of your document.  It is worth noting that the editable version in Google Docs will not show the page numbers. This is by design.

Comment: Doesn't work in Presentation :)

Answer (score 0):

I needed to have Page # of # inside of some text in my header.  I couldn't get the header to show a page number.  I found that I could add it to the footer, then copy it, then paste it wherever I wanted in the header.

Answer (score -1):

Check out this YouTube video that walks you through the steps of adding page numbers to Google Docs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ka5IRhC6bPg

- The Gooru

Comment: Please add the relevant info to the answer instead of just linking to a video. Thanks!

Comment: Without the link, there is no useful information in this "answer".