# Adding Pagenumbers to Google Drive Presentation?

Tags: google-slides

Can someone tell me how can I add page numbers to my Google Drive Presentation?

I've read that it should be under "Insert" but there's nothing even remotely relevant there. Here’s a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: See [this](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/15262/1512) question.

Comment: Works for Docs, not Presentations. I'm not seeing any of those options.

Comment: As of now, Google Slides does support master slide functionality, however page numbers are still not included in the newest release.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately page numbers in ***Presentations*** hasn't been implemented yet.

> We don't currently support master slide functionality, so you'll need
>   to insert numbers and logos manually.

[Source](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/docs/sg83y0BBflo/tHCMDSYGEBoJ)

Its likely that i will be in the future - but no idea when.

Someone on another forum suggested a workaround by using the features built into Adobe Acrobat to add the page numbers (Open the document in acrobat, open the tools menu, goto Pages > Header and Footer > Add Footer/Header)

Comment: As of Dec 1, 2014 this feature was added. See announcement here: https://plus.google.com/+GoogleDrive/posts/fDKE7htJ2Ma

Comment: Pity that font color cannot be customized, so it's unreadable on dark background presentations.

Answer (score 1):

This feature was added to Google Slides in December 2014. See [this help page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1694980?hl=en) for instructions on how to add numbers to slides.